# Nested div tags in IE and Firefox

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox

I'm having some trouble here with a nested div tag.  As you can see from the image below, it's showing one way in IE and another way in Firefox.  I actually prefer the IE layout.  Any idea how to fix it?

Here's my code:

```
<div style="width:1200; ">
      <p align = "center"><b><font size="4">Joke  Of The Day</font></b><p>
        <div style="width: 80px; float:left; margin:4; "><img src="FredFlipoff.jpg" width="80px" height="80px"></div>
        <div style="width: 280px;>
            <p align="justify"><font size=2">To smooth over her recent negative comments about his  presidency, Hillary Clinton said she and Barack Obama will "Hug-it-Out" next time they meet. Hearing  this, Bill Clinton said he also will  "Hug-it-Out" with political rivals Megan Fox, Angelina Jolie,  Sophia Vergara, Scarlett Johanson, and that Hot waitress who works at The Olive Garden.
            </font><br><hr id='hrdotted' /></div>
</div>
```

The two outputs are like so:

[image]

It's like Firefox is wrapping the text around the image for some reason, and in doing so it's making the div width shorter than it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to the style of the second div display:inline-block.

```
<div style="width:1200; ">
      <p align = "center"><b><font size="4">Joke  Of The Day</font></b><p>
    <div style="width: 80px; float:left; margin:4; "><img src="FredFlipoff.jpg" width="80px" height="80px"></div>
    <div style="display: inline-block; width: 280px;>
        <p align="justify"><font size=2">To smooth over her recent negative comments about his  presidency, Hillary Clinton said she and Barack Obama will "Hug-it-Out" next time they meet. Hearing  this, Bill Clinton said he also will  "Hug-it-Out" with political rivals Megan Fox, Angelina Jolie,  Sophia Vergara, Scarlett Johanson, and that Hot waitress who works at The Olive Garden.
        </font><br><hr id='hrdotted' /></div>
</div>
```

See here:
http://jsfiddle.net/cmp3vkwu/

Comment: Someone is also likely to say to put those styles in a stylesheet because it is considered bad form to use inline-styles, but I figure you're experimenting right now and will do that later. Just a heads-up.

Comment: Worked perfectly.  And you're right, I need a seperate stylesheet.  I've just been out of HTML for so long and I promised a friend I'd whip this up quickly, and he's bugging the snot out of me.  :o)

Comment: Fantastic! I hear ya. It cost me a job opportunity by having an inline style in a rushed test they gave me, so I know how tough people can be about that rule. Me mentioning it probably deterred any comment on it from others. I'm glad it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Just add the below given css to prevent the wrapping up of text around the image.

```
 img {
     float: left;
 }
 p {
     overflow: hidden;
 }
 div {
     display:block;
 }
```

### Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/6f5ff2g0/2/)

Answer (score 0):

To overcome the general problem of browsers rendering CSS differently, or having different default CSS stylings for elements, I like to include [Normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) in my projects. Its aim is to reduce these kind of frustrating discrepancies and it does a pretty good job of creating a level web-development playing field.